# Locally deleted git-managed files aren't removed from the server

Tags: git, web-deployment, git-tower

Apologies if the title for this is misleading or incorrect - feel free to edit it.

I have a website that I version control using Git. I'm using Tower as a GUI for it. I'm using [GitGo](https://gitgo.io/) as a deployment server. When I make changes to my site locally, I commit the changes then push them to the remote branch. GitGo monitors this for changes, then automatically deploys those changes to the live website.

**Problem**: When I delete files from my local repository, they don't seem to get deleted on the server? For example, I've just deleted a folder locally, committed that deletion and deployed to the server. The deployment went through with no issues, but the folder and its files are still on the server.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tracked this down to being a deployment service problem. The files are being deleted from the remote repository, but those files aren't being deleted from the server. Using GitGo as a deployment service. Unless I discover anything new, I'm putting this down to a problem with GitGo.